# Sticky sidebar doesn't stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, sidebar, sticky

I have a sticky sidebar on my page using the following script:

```
$(function() {
            var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
            var topPadding = 15;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
```

The problem is that it should stop scrolling when it reaches the Middle Block Div. At the moment it doesn't stop scrolling and it pushes all the rest of the content down. Is there a way to fix this?

**[- DEMO -](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYMNrW)**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the position of `.middle-block` and stop the sidebar from scrolling at that point (minus the height of the sidebar).

Change your jQuery function to:

```
$(function() {
    var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
    var mbOffset = $(".middle-block").offset();
    var mbPos = mbOffset.top - $("#sidebar").outerHeight() - 30; /*30px extra space*/
    var topPadding = 15;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top ) {
            if(  $(window).scrollTop() < mbPos ) {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            }
        } else {
            $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        };
    });
});
```

[**Updated Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEzeJX)

Answer (score 2):

you have check if Sidebar has been moved to Middle Box, if so just stop the sidebar to animate.
**like this :**

```
$(function() {
            var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
            var boxOffset = $(".middle-block").offset().top;
            var sidebarHeight = parseInt($("#sidebar").outerHeight());
            var topPadding = 15;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    if(($(window).scrollTop()+sidebarHeight)<boxOffset){
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
```

check it live here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lokeshpahal/Loo7t3b1/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works fine however I chose the above answer from LinkinTED.